# Displaying server information at login prompt (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I'm wondering if there's a way to customize the Ubuntu server login prompt. Currently it shows the following:

```
Ubuntu 13.10 fw tty1
fw login: _
```

I know there's /etc/motd for the message of the day, also .bashrc for bash customization for each user, but how do I change the login prompt post?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

the file you search for is /etc/issue and for non-local /etc/issue.net

if you want to have the message be shown via ssh aswell:

This statement has to be set in /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
Banner /etc/issue.net
```